# What does the "Base" keyword mean in Julia?

Tags: julia

I saw [this example](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/interfaces/) in the Julia language documentation. It uses something called `Base`. What is this `Base`?

```
immutable Squares    
    count::Int    
end

Base.start(::Squares) = 1  
Base.next(S::Squares, state) = (state*state, state+1)  
Base.done(S::Squares, s) = s > S.count;  
Base.eltype(::Type{Squares}) = Int # Note that this is defined for the type  
Base.length(S::Squares) = S.count;
```

Comment: `Base` can be thought of as the Julia standard library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Base` is a module which defines many of the functions, types and macros used in the Julia language. You can view the files for everything it contains [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/base) or call `whos(Base)` to print a list.

In fact, these functions and types (which include things like `sum` and `Int`) are so fundamental to the language that they are included in Julia's top-level scope by default.

This means that we can just use `sum` instead of `Base.sum` every time we want to use that particular function. Both names refer to the same thing:

```
Julia> sum === Base.sum
true

Julia> @which sum # show where the name is defined
Base
```

So why, you might ask, is it necessary is write things like `Base.start` instead of simply `start`?

The point is that `start` is just a name. We are free to rebind names in the top-level scope to anything we like. For instance `start = 0` will rebind the name 'start' to the integer 0 (so that it no longer refers to `Base.start`).

Concentrating now on the specific example in docs, if we simply wrote `start(::Squares) = 1`, then we find that we have created a *new* function with 1 method:

```
Julia> start
start (generic function with 1 method)
```

But Julia's iterator interface (invoked using the `for` loop) requires us to add the new method to `Base.start`! We haven't done this and so we get an error if we try to iterate:

```
julia> for i in Squares(7)
                  println(i)
       end

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching start(::Squares)
```

By updating the `Base.start` function instead by writing `Base.start(::Squares) = 1`, the iterator interface can use the method for the `Squares` type and iteration will work as we expect (as long as `Base.done` and `Base.next` are also extended for this type).

Comment: Thanks for the great exaplanation. One more question - What does Base.start(::Squares) mean?

Comment: No problem! That is the signature for a method for the Base.start function to be used with the Squares type. Julia dispatches methods based on types, so this is the code it will execute for iteration over Squares(7), etc.

Answer (score 7):

I'll grant that for something so fundamental, the explanation is buried a bit far down in the documentation, but http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/modules/#standard-modules describes this:

> There are three important standard modules: Main, Core, and Base.
>
> Base is the standard library (the contents of base/). All modules
>   implicitly contain using Base, since this is needed in the vast
>   majority of cases.